# Spotify Malformed Json

Tags: php, json, spotify, guzzle

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play` endpoint keeps throwing an error

> Client error: `PUT https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=b3be3728123923782d72b3c0b5e7e3d91b9dfb10` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error" : { "status" : 400, "message" : "Malformed json" } }`

Here's my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('PUT', 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=".$request->device_id', [
    "headers" => [
        "Authorization" =>  ["Bearer " . $session_owner->spotify_token],
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ],
    "form_params" => [
        "uris" => ["spotify:track:" . $request->spotify_song_id]
    ]
]);
```

So far this is the only endpoint that gives me this problem. If I comment out `context_uri` line, then the playback of the last track on last active device starts properly.

Here's what that line translate to:

```
"form_params": {
    "uris": ["spotify:track:2Hy7ypRUKL4OPqtNlzBHWM"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotify requires the request body to be a JSON string but you are sending URL encoded form data.

Change the content type to `application/json` and `form_params` to `json`:

```
"headers" => [
    "Authorization" =>  ["Bearer " . $session_owner->spotify_token],
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
],
"json" => [
    "context_uri" => "spotify:track:" . $request->spotify_song_id,
]
```

Guzzle will now send the JSON as the complete request body with no form params.